# (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file when using absolute file path in sqlite3 connection string in sqlalchemy on windows

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a database engine from a connection string using sqlite3 and sqlalchemy but am running into issues.

My particular details are that I want to use an absolute filepath from the os module in the connection string (this makes it easier when I deploy it only python anywhere) and am currently working on windows.

The most viewed answer to this question can be found here:  [OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985657/operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file) but its answers did not work for me.

Here is my current directory structure:

```
 /db
   -- assets.db
 /app
   -- load_engine.py
   -- models.py
```

The idea is that I want to initialize my sqlalchemy connection from a function in the `load_engine` file, but reference the file path to `/db/assets.db` into it.

This is the function inside `load_engine`:

```
def load_engine():
    
    db_file = os.environ.get('database_file')
    
    script_path = os.path.realpath('__file__')
    parent_path = os.path.dirname(script_path)
    db_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep,parent_path, "db", db_file)
    
    engine = create_engine(fr"sqlite:///{db_path}")
    return engine
```

I'm trying to invoke this function in the `models.py` file in the following way:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Assets(Base):
    """Main table that will hold the list of ticker names"""
    __tablename__ = 'assets'
    
    id     = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    ticker = Column(String(250), nullable = False, unique = True)
    type   = Column(String(100), nullable = False)

class BarData(Base):
    """Will hold daily bar data from yahoo finance"""
    __tablename__ = 'bardata'
    
    id        = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    ticker    = Column(String(250), ForeignKey("assets.ticker"), nullable = False)
    open      = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    high      = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    low       = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    close     = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    volume    = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    dividends = Column(Float, nullable = False)
    splits    = Column(Float, nullable = True)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = load_engine()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

And when I run this I get the error, presumably because my filepath is wrong.  I've tried deleting the `assets.db` file to see if that changed, but it didn't work.  I also tried using 4 forward slashes vs. 3, but also got the same message.

If I reference a file that's in the same directory it works fine, so I would assume the issue is the filepath.

**EDIT:**

Per comments, output of engine is the following:

```
Engine(sqlite:////C:\Users\Jonat\trading\app\db\assets.db)
```

Comment: So what does `db_path` actually contain after you've constructed it?

Comment: better check what you really have in path. Char \ has special meaning in string (even in path) and \t` in \trading can be treated as tab, The same with \Uxxx in \Users which is for unicode. You could also check if it should have four / in sqlite://// - maybe it should be only three / - and then you shouldn't use os.path.sep in os.path.join

Comment: after checking some source I think all problem is that you have four / in `sqlite://// `. It should be `three / + absolute_path` but in Windows absolute path starts with `C:\ `, not with / , but you use `/C:\ `. On Linux absolute path starts with / so finally it looks like four / - Windows `"sqlite:///" + "C:\Users\Jonat\..."`, Linux/Unix/MacOS `"sqlite:///" + "/home/Jonat/..."`